# Magento upload image to skin directory instead of media

Tags: php, magento, upload

In the system config module I created, I 've added the specific field into the groups section:

```
<image_upload  translate='label'>
<frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">adam/promotion</upload_dir>
<base_url type="media" scope_info="1">adam/promotion</base_url>
<sort_order>1</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

This xml code successfully stores the uploaded image to directory

```
media/adam/promotion
```

Is there a way to change the location in which the uploaded image are going to be stored to 'skin' instead of 'media'? I 've tried changing the upload_dir and base_url to:

```
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/**skin**" scope_info="1">general/promotion</upload_dir>
<base_url type="**skin**" scope_info="1">general/promotion</base_url>
```

but it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial

The base image upload path **IS NOT system/filesystem/media**, but it’s the value of the **Magento System Configuration at system/filesystem/media** (which resolves to {{root_dir}}/media in a default Community Edition install).

I strongly don't recommend trying to put files in the `skin` folder using this method, but you could try creating a new system config with value `{{root_dir}}/skin`